# Factoring polynomials and equating coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, factoring

I am studying Factorising polynomials and equating coefficients at the moment, and up until now all has been well. I have no problem working these out up as high as the third degree as there are plenty of examples. 
Questions like this:

Factorise the expression $x^3 - 17x^2 + 54x - 8$ given $(x-4)$ is a factor.

I can work this out using $(x-4)(\alpha x^2 + \beta x + \gamma)$ and then equating the coefficients.

However, in the end of block exercises some of the questions are 4th degree polynomials and I don't know where to begin. 
With the polynomial $x^4 -7x^3 + 3x^2 + 31x + 20$ where $(x+1)$ is a factor for example.

Do I use the same procedure but start a degree higher, like $(x+1)(\alpha x^3 + \beta x^2 + \gamma x + \delta)$  and move on down to figure out the 2nd degree after that?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Comment: But $x-1$ is not a factor of $x^3-17x^2+54x-8$, and $x+1$ is not a factor of $x^4-7x^3+31x+20$.

Comment: mal, it would be helpful if you would address @Gerry's comment. Did you make up the "questions like this" yourself? If so, maybe we could suggest some that are coherent.

Comment: my apologies, that was a typo, it should have been (x-4), I've corrected it now.

Comment: Good. But what about the other one in my comment?

Comment: dear god what am I like??? updated, I left out $+3x^2$ , no wonder I'm failing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> With the polynomial $x^4 -7x^3 + 3x^2 + 31x + 20$ where $(x+1)$ is a
>   factor for example.
>
> Do I use the same procedure but start a degree higher, like
>   $(x+1)(\alpha x^3 + \beta x^2 + \gamma x + \delta)$  and move on down
>   to figure out the 2nd degree after that?

There are other techniques, namely the [polynomial long division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) as mentioned in a comment by pedja, the [Ruffini's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini's_rule) and for polynomials with integer coefficients the [rational root theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), but you can apply the method of equating coefficients to

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
P(x) &:&=x^{4}-7x^{3}+3x^{2}+31x+20 =\left( x+1\right) \left( \alpha x^{3}+\beta x^{2}+\gamma x+\delta \right). \end{eqnarray*}\;\; \tag{1}$$

Expanding the RHS and comparing with the LHS, where the coefficient of $x^{4}$ is $1$, you would conclude that $\alpha =1$ and are left with a simpler equality

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
P(x) &:&=x^{4}-7x^{3}+3x^{2}+31x+20=\left( x+1\right) \left( x^{3}+\beta x^{2}+\gamma x+\delta \right)  \\
&=&x^{4}+\left( \beta +1\right) x^{3}+\left( \beta +\gamma \right)
x^{2}+\left( \gamma +\delta \right) x+\delta .
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Equating coefficients you get the simple system of four linear equations
$$
\begin{equation*}
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\delta =20 \\ 
\gamma +\delta =31 \\ 
\beta +\gamma =3 \\ 
\beta +1=-7,
\end{array}
\right. 
\end{equation*}$$
whose solution is $\delta =20,\beta =-8,\gamma =11$. So

$$\begin{equation*}
x^{4}-7x^{3}+3x^{2}+31x+20=\left( x+1\right) \left(
x^{3}-8x^{2}+11x+20\right). 
\end{equation*}\tag{2}$$
Now by direct inspection (or by the rational root theorem, since $1,2,4$ and $5$ are the positive divisors of $20$) you can find that $x=-1$ is a zero of the cubic polynomial $Q(x):=x^{3}-8x^{2}+11x+20$, ie $Q(-1)=0$. Applying a similar method to $Q(x)$ you would find that

$$\begin{equation*}
Q(x)=x^{3}-8x^{2}+11x+20=\left( x+1\right) \left( x-4\right) \left(
x-5\right) .
\end{equation*}$$

Consequently, 
$$\begin{equation*}
x^{4}-7x^{3}+3x^{2}+31x+20=\left( x+1\right) ^{2}\left( x-4\right) \left(
x-5\right). 
\end{equation*}\tag{3}$$

A shorter method is the [Ruffini's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruffini's_rule) applied to the polynomial division of $P(x)$ by $(x-r)$. This case (with $P(x)=x^{4}-7x^{3}+3x^{2}+31x+20$ and $r=-1,P(r)=0$, )  is shown bellow, where the remainder is $P(r)=s$.

[image]

Comment: Exemplary answer! (+1).

Comment: Many, many thanks Américo - I will study your comprehensive answer.

Comment: @mal, You are welcome!